# How to iterate through array to pull out properties for specifc keys?

Tags: ios, swift

Im working with decoded JSON, and specifically i need to work within an array to pull out a property of a specific object based on its key.
JSON looks like the following, and Im needing to pull out the filenames for `"fanart"` and `"clearlogo"`

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "Success",
  "data": {
    "count": 1,
    "base_url": {
      "original": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/original/",
      "small": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/small/",
      "thumb": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/thumb/",
      "cropped_center_thumb": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/cropped_center_thumb/",
      "medium": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/medium/",
      "large": "https://cdn.thegamesdb.net/images/large/"
    },
    "images": {
      "2578": [
        {
          "id": 5512,
          "type": "boxart",
          "side": "front",
          "filename": "boxart/front/2578-1.jpg",
          "resolution": "1533x2155"
        },
        {
          "id": 5513,
          "type": "boxart",
          "side": "back",
          "filename": "boxart/back/2578-1.jpg",
          "resolution": "1522x2155"
        },
        {
          "id": 87092,
          "type": "fanart",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "fanart/2578-1.jpg",
          "resolution": "1920x1080"
        },
        {
          "id": 87093,
          "type": "fanart",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "fanart/2578-2.jpg",
          "resolution": "1920x1080"
        },
        {
          "id": 87094,
          "type": "fanart",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "fanart/2578-3.jpg",
          "resolution": "1920x1080"
        },
        {
          "id": 87095,
          "type": "clearlogo",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "clearlogo/2578.png",
          "resolution": "400x300"
        },
        {
          "id": 87096,
          "type": "screenshot",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "screenshots/2578-1.jpg",
          "resolution": null
        },
        {
          "id": 87097,
          "type": "screenshot",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "screenshots/2578-2.jpg",
          "resolution": null
        },
        {
          "id": 87098,
          "type": "fanart",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "fanart/2578-4.jpg",
          "resolution": "1920x1080"
        },
        {
          "id": 87099,
          "type": "screenshot",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "screenshots/2578-3.jpg",
          "resolution": null
        },
        {
          "id": 87100,
          "type": "screenshot",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "screenshots/2578-4.jpg",
          "resolution": null
        },
        {
          "id": 87101,
          "type": "fanart",
          "side": null,
          "filename": "fanart/2578-5.jpg",
          "resolution": "1920x1080"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

The key `"2578"`is dynamic and changes by the game.   I have this succesfuly decoding with the following:

```
struct GameDBData : Decodable {
    let data : GameDataImages
}

struct GameDataImages : Decodable {

    let images : Images

}

struct Images : Decodable {

    var innerArray: [String: [Inner]]

    struct Inner: Decodable {
        let id : Int
        let fileName  : String
        let type : String

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case id
            case fileName = "filename"
            case type

        }
    }

    private struct CustomCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue : String
        init?(stringValue : String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self)
        self.innerArray = [String: [Inner]]()
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let value = try container.decode([Inner].self, forKey: CustomCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
            self.innerArray[key.stringValue] = value
        }
    }

}
```

Ive tried `firstIndex(where:)` but Im not getting anywhere with it.  How can i iterate the `2578` array to get the `filename` for `type: "clearlogo"` and `type: "fanart"` im needing?

Comment: You have an Array of Inner. An Inner has a `type`. Some of the Inner objects have a `type` that is `"fanart"`. What's the hard part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have array of **Inner**.Something like this,

```
var array:[Inner] = [_yourData]
```

If we assume your array should have only one object with type "fanart" & "clearlogo" for each.we can get each filename using ,

```
let fanartFileName = array.filter({$0.type == "fanart"})[0].fileName
let clearlogoFileName = array.filter({$0.type == "clearlogo"})[0].fileName
```

some times your array havn't any record for these types.or have more than one,

```
let fanartArray = ar.filter({$0.type == "fanart"})

if fanartArray.count > 0 {
    fanartArray.forEach { (record) in
        print(record.fileName)
    }
}
```

Comment: `var array:[Inner] = [_yourData]`.  My data includes the `String:Inner`, im trying to load it into `yourData` with `gameDataImages?.data.images.innerArray` however I cant drop the String.  How can I get access to only the Inner values of my data?  btw `gameDataImages : GameDBData?`

Comment: Had to modify it a bit, but got it working: ```var array:[Images.Inner] = []
                let inner = self.gameDataImages?.data.images.innerArray
                for (_, value) in inner! {
                   array = value
                }```